# Existence of $p_{0}$ and a linear isometry

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations

Let $G: R^3 \to R^3$ be a map such that

$$|G(p)−G(q)| = |p −q|$$ for all $$ p, q \in R^3$$

Prove that there exists $p_{0} \in R^3$ and a linear isometry F of the vector space $R^3$ such that
$$G(p) = F(p)+p_{0} $$ for all $$ p \in R^3$$

I consider this map

$$F: R^3 \to R^3$$
$$p \to F(p) =G(p)-p_{0}$$

where $G(0)=p_{0}$

and with this, we obtain $F(0)=0$ y $|F(p)|=|p|$

Now, how can i prove that F is linear? i need linearity to prove another properties and get the conclusion that F is an isometry. any ideas?

Comment: Any isometry $G$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is affine, i.e., $G(x)=f(x)+x_0$, where $F$ lis linear.

Comment: but this is the point. we must prove that F is linear.

Comment: And exactly this is proved in the duplicate (or in similar posts here). $F$ linear means, that there exists a matrix $A$ with $F(x)=Ax$, see the post.